# How to write regex strings for the input pattern attribute

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation, pseudo-class

I have a regex that works in Javascript but not as a `pattern` attribute of the `input` tag.

The regex below tests if the string has at least 3 chars which are not numbers.

```js
/(?=^([^\d]*)$)(?=(\w){3,})/
```

In an "input" tag, I used the same regex string:

```
pattern="(?=^([^\d]*)$)(?=(\w){3,})"
```

This does not work as the pseudo-class `:invalid` is always active.

How should I formulate the regex string in the pattern?

Comment: Do you mean the string must have no digits and the first 3 are word characters?

Comment: at least 3 characters and no digit, yes

Comment: Then a simple `pattern="\D{3,}"` should work.

Comment: indeed! Saying that, I don't see why I can't write the first one in the pattern

Comment: It is easy to explain: your pattern only consists of lookaheads that do not consume any text, and the pattern attribute regex must consume the whole string.

Comment: Also, `\w` matches digits. So, even if we do not take into account the fact the regex must consume the whole string, your first regex seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [`pattern` attribute documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern). Note:

- The pattern attribute regex is compiled with `v` flag now
- The `anchoredPattern` is a sum of `^(?:`, followed by *`pattern`*, followed by `)$`.

So, your first `(?=^([^\d]*)$)(?=(\w){3,})` pattern is actually compiled as `/^(?:(?=^([^\d]*)$)(?=(\w){3,}))$/v` and does not match any string because right after the start of string, there must be the string end, but lookaheads require at least three word characters at the start.

Since all you need is to match a string that has at least three chars and contains no digits, you can simply use

```html
pattern="\D{3,}"
```

It will be compiled as `/^(?:\D{3,})$/v` and will match what you need.

Comment: This means that you can't use "and". This worked in JS with `/regex/.test(text)` but I understand now why this does not work with the pattern attribute. Thks.

Comment: @NevD You can use "and". Just you do not need that.